# Kendo does not accept custom click handler for grid's edit button

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I've tried the following jQuery script, but it does not seem to work:

```
$('td').on('click', '.k-grid-edit', function() {
   alert("Edit button clicked!");
});
```

Full code example:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mpo21o4a/)

Comment: need more explanation..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use main div class instead of dynamic `td` for `delegation` like,

```
$('.k-grid-content') // use grid-content class instead of td
  .on('click', 'a.k-grid-edit', function() { // use a.k-grid-edit instead of .k-grid-edit
    alert("Edit button clicked!");
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/mpo21o4a/1/)**